# Archive/Compress Command FTP Through Terminal?

Tags: ftp, terminal, archive, compression

Is it possible to compress a folder and create a .zip on my server through a command in terminal via FTP? Is there a archive command? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

What I believe you want to do is ssh onto your server and use the tar command.

```
tar -cf archive.tar contents/
```

> Takes everything from contents/ and puts it into archive.tar

[You can find more information here.](http://www.webhostgear.com/35.html)